# DB query returns only first matching result

Tags: php, silex, bolt-cms

```
// Get all categories
$query = "SELECT name FROM bolt_taxonomy WHERE taxonomytype = :taxonomytype AND contenttype = :contenttype";
$map = array(
    ':taxonomytype'  => 'categories',
    ':contenttype' => 'news',
);
$categories = $this->app['db']->fetchAssoc($query, $map);

$response = $this->app->json(array('categories' => $categories));
return $response;
```

Returns:

```
{
    "categories": {
        "name": "life"
    }
}
```

Which is just the first entry that matches the above condition on the bolt_taxonomy table. How can I get it to return the whole list of categories?

Comment: Does the `WHERE` clause satisfy more than one records?

Comment: you need to use a while loop to get all the records.

Comment: @jim could you elaborate? How can I implement this?

Comment: @Ranjith yes, there are around 20 records that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @babbaggeii Looking at this quick i would try `while($response = $this->app->json(array('categories'=>$categories))) { return $response;}`

Answer (score 1):

This is now solved by using `fetchAll`:

```
// Get the category
    $query = "SELECT name FROM bolt_taxonomy WHERE taxonomytype = 'categories' AND contenttype = 'news'";

    $categories = $this->app['db']->query($query);
    $result = $categories->fetchAll();

    $response = $this->app->json(array('categories' => $result));
    return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate using `while` or `foreach` loop.

```
$categories = $this->app['db']->fetchAssoc($query, $map);

foreach($categories as $category) {
   $result[] = $category;
}
$response = $this->app->json($result);
echo $response;
return $response;
```

Comment: That just returns the first result again `{
"categories": "life"
}`

Comment: Sorry. Check my updated answer with `$result` to `$result[]` array.

Comment: If nothing matches, you would end up with `$result` being undefined.